# tap state over area on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, mobile

I am building a mobile site. i currently am using jquery ui as it loads from a cdn quicker than having jquery mobile

My question is really around how to deal with hover state / tappable areas?

I would like to show the user they have clicked on the button.

Is there a good way to implement this - should I be using hover or is there a better way of doing this?

Sorry know this is a bit random

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the hover state as there's no way to know if the user is dangling their finger above the button, you can use the active state however. The active state becomes...well...active when the button is pressed, then you could make the button image/styling be 'depressed' to look like it is being pressed in, and it'll then go back to normal when the user releases their finger, just like a real button.

This can be done entirely with CSS, no need for any javascript. The default jquery-ui button does use the active state already.